# Mail sending from phpdesktop application in windows I have to refer this Project website: http://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop

Tags: codeigniter-3, phpdesktop

Mail sending from phpdesktop application in windows I have to refer this Project website: http://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop.

I used the package name Phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-RC-PHP-7.1.3 Here no mail config file in php.ini so how to send mail from the desktop application to server.

php.ini config file contain

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OvGU.png)

Can I send mail from desktop application through any email?.
And how to assemble the mail config for my desktop application project?

Comment: See https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Knowledge-Base#mail-function-doesnt-work

Comment: @Czarek Tomczak Thanks lot friend

Comment: @Czarek Tomczak Clear My problem.